# finding distance between two points on Image even when image is scaled

Tags: javascript, image, fabricjs

I have an Image loaded on canvas. I want to find the distance between to points on this image. But because the image can be bit small user can zoom in (scale image) and then click on two points find the distance. To get points clicked on any image is the easy part

```
myImage.on('mousedown', function(e){

    console.log(e.layerX + " "+e.layerY);
}
```

though I am not quite sure that layerX is the better messurment. What If the user has scaled the image. Won't that mean that the distance will be bigger? So what is the correct way? Is it to scale down the layerX and layerY before calculating the distance?

```
myImage.on('mousedown', function(e){
    var x, y;
    x = e.layerX / this.getScaleX();
    y = e.layerY / this.getScaleY();
    calculateDistance(x, y);

});
```

Would the above calculate a more accurate distance? At a second level I want to to take this distance and then recalibrate another picture according to the distance I calibrated (doing the opposite thing). use case:

Users wants to take two points but scales the image up. The destination is calculated and the image is scaled down to its original state. User add a new picture on canvas, which shows something that I know its physical width and height. So system re-calculates pixel width and height of the image based on the calibration done before. So correct procedure would be

1. Take two points (on scaled up image)
2. Find distance
3. Divide distance with scale ratio
4. Use the distance

or

1. Take two points (on scaled up image)
2. divide layerX and layerY with scale ratio
3. calculate distance
4. Use the distance

Which one is more correct?

Answer (score 0):

I would get the two points and divided by the image ratio.

[See JSBin](http://jsbin.com/tefipo/6/edit)

**html**

```
<div id="holder">
    <img src="http://30.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lzq1rfNV7N1qhze6fo1_500.jpg" />
</div>
```

**css**

```
#holder {
  width: 100%;
  height:auto;
}

#holder img {
  width: 100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var last = {
  x:0,
  y:0
};
//dim is the original image dimensions
var dim = {
  width:500,
  height:427
};
var img = $("#holder img");
img.bind('mousedown',checkpoint);

function checkpoint(e){
  // ratio is the scaled image width/height
  // divided by the original width/height
  var ratio = {
    x:img.width()/dim.width,
    y:img.height()/dim.height
  };

  point = {
    x:e.clientX / ratio.x,
    y:e.clientY / ratio.y
  };
  var dis = distance(last.x,last.y,point.x,point.y);
  last=point;
  console.log(dis);
}

function distance(x1, y1, x2,y2){
    var dx = x2-x1;
    var dy = y2-y1;
    return Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
}
```

updated per comment

Comment: what is dim. Is it the new dimensions after scale?

Comment: dim is the original image dimensions

Comment: did that answer your question?

Comment: Haven't True it yet that's why  I haven't checked it yet. Is that mathematical correct? It looks like it just want to make sure :)

Comment: The math is right, I wrote it for another project. I had to brush up on my trigonometry. A quick test would be to swap the image for a grid image with pixel points. If you do that be sure to update the image dimensions.